# ElasticSearch Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, illegalargumentexception

I'm using Elasticsearch latest version on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm having a little issue on putting data on it.

here is my json document (relevant part of it)

```
{   "products" : {
    "232CDFDW89ENUXRB" : {
        "sku" : "232CDFDW89ENUXRB",
        "productFamily" : "Compute Instance",
        "attributes" : {
            "servicecode" : "AmazonEC2",
            "location" : "US East (N. Virginia)",
            "locationType" : "AWS Region",
            "instanceType" : "d2.8xlarge",
            "currentGeneration" : "Yes",
            "instanceFamily" : "Storage optimized",
            "vcpu" : "36",
            "physicalProcessor" : "Intel Xeon E5-2676v3 (Haswell)",
            "clockSpeed" : "2.4 GHz",
            "memory" : "244 GiB",
            "storage" : "24 x 2000 HDD",
            "networkPerformance" : "10 Gigabit",
            "processorArchitecture" : "64-bit",
            "tenancy" : "Host",
            "operatingSystem" : "Linux",
            "licenseModel" : "No License required",
            "usagetype" : "HostBoxUsage:d2.8xlarge",
            "operation" : "RunInstances",
            "enhancedNetworkingSupported" : "Yes",
            "preInstalledSw" : "NA",
            "processorFeatures" : "Intel AVX; Intel AVX2; Intel Turbo" }
        }
    }   
}
```

and here's the returning response from ES when i try "PUT http://localhost:9200/aws"

```
{ "error": {
"root_cause": [
  {
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "unknown setting [index.products.232CDFDW89ENUXRB.attributes.clockSpeed] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
  }
],
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "unknown setting [index.products.232CDFDW89ENUXRB.attributes.clockSpeed] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings" }, "status": 400 }
```

Seems to me ES thinks that "clockSpeed" is some sort of setting...?
I was hoping to use dynamic mapping to speed the process up instead of first mapping all the document and then importing it in ES.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are missing `document type` and `document id` while indexing a document through `PUT http://localhost:9200/aws` command.

Proper way to index document is:

```
POST my-index/my-type/my-id-1
{
  "name": "kibana"
}
```

i.e You have to provide `document type` (here my-type) and `document id` (here my-id-1). Note that document id is optional here so if you don't provide one then elasticsearch create one alphanumeric id for you.

Other couple of ways indexing a doc:

```
POST my-index/my-type
{
  "name": "kibana"
}

//if you want to index document through PUT then you must provide document id
PUT my-index/my-type/my-id-1
{
  "name": "kibana"
}
```

**Note:** If automatic index creation is disabled then you have to create index before indexing documents.

Comment: If above answer resolves your issue then you can close the question by accepting it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Given a clean mapping, `XPOST` works perfectly for me on elasticsearch 5.1.1.**,

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/productsapp/productdocs -d '
{   "products" : {
     "sku1" : {
         "sku" : "SKU-Name",
         "productFamily" : "Compute Instance",
         "attributes" : {
             "servicecode" : "AmazonEC2",
             "location" : "US East (N. Virginia)",
             "locationType" : "AWS Region",
             "instanceType" : "d2.8xlarge",
             "currentGeneration" : "Yes",
             "instanceFamily" : "Storage optimized",
             "vcpu" : "36",
             "physicalProcessor" : "Intel Xeon E5-2676v3 (Haswell)",
             "clockSpeed" : "2.4 GHz",
             "memory" : "244 GiB",
             "storage" : "24 x 2000 HDD",
             "networkPerformance" : "10 Gigabit",
             "processorArchitecture" : "64-bit",
             "tenancy" : "Host",
             "operatingSystem" : "Linux",
             "licenseModel" : "No License required",
             "usagetype" : "HostBoxUsage:d2.8xlarge",
             "operation" : "RunInstances",
             "enhancedNetworkingSupported" : "Yes",
             "preInstalledSw" : "NA",
             "processorFeatures" : "Intel AVX; Intel AVX2; Intel Turbo" }
         }
     }   
 }'
{"_index":"productsapp","_type":"productdocs","_id":"AVuhXdYYUiSguAb0FsSX","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}
```

**`GET` the inserted doc**

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/productsapp/productdocs/_search
{"took":11,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"productsapp","_type":"productdocs","_id":"AVuhXdYYUiSguAb0FsSX","_score":1.0,"_source":{   "products" : {
    "sku1" : {
        "sku" : "SKU-Name",
        "productFamily" : "Compute Instance",
        "attributes" : {
            "servicecode" : "AmazonEC2",
            "location" : "US East (N. Virginia)",
            "locationType" : "AWS Region",
            "instanceType" : "d2.8xlarge",
            "currentGeneration" : "Yes",
            "instanceFamily" : "Storage optimized",
            "vcpu" : "36",
            "physicalProcessor" : "Intel Xeon E5-2676v3 (Haswell)",
            "clockSpeed" : "2.4 GHz",
            "memory" : "244 GiB",
            "storage" : "24 x 2000 HDD",
            "networkPerformance" : "10 Gigabit",
            "processorArchitecture" : "64-bit",
            "tenancy" : "Host",
            "operatingSystem" : "Linux",
            "licenseModel" : "No License required",
            "usagetype" : "HostBoxUsage:d2.8xlarge",
            "operation" : "RunInstances",
            "enhancedNetworkingSupported" : "Yes",
            "preInstalledSw" : "NA",
            "processorFeatures" : "Intel AVX; Intel AVX2; Intel Turbo" }
        }
    }   
}}]}}
```

The mapping it creates is as below, with `clockSpeed` as `text` type.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/productsapp/productdocs/_mapping?pretty=true
{
  "productsapp" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "productdocs" : {
        "properties" : {
          "products" : {
            "properties" : {
              "232CDFDW89ENUXRB" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "attributes" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "clockSpeed" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "currentGeneration" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "enhancedNetworkingSupported" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "instanceFamily" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "instanceType" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "licenseModel" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "location" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "locationType" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "memory" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "networkPerformance" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "operatingSystem" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "operation" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "physicalProcessor" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "preInstalledSw" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "processorArchitecture" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "processorFeatures" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "servicecode" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "storage" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "tenancy" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "usagetype" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "vcpu" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "productFamily" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                      "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "sku" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                      "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can you check you mapping for `attributes.clockSpeed` and make sure its not screwed up.

**And if you want to update the document do `XPUT` on the id of first document (which is `AVuhXdYYUiSguAb0FsSX`),**

In following example, I am updating `sku` field to `"sku name updated"`

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/productsapp/productdocs/AVuhXdYYUiSguAb0FsSX -d '
{
          "products" : {
            "sku1" : {
              "sku" : "sku name updated",
              "productFamily" : "Compute Instance",
              "attributes" : {
                "servicecode" : "AmazonEC2",
                "location" : "US East (N. Virginia)",
                "locationType" : "AWS Region",
                "instanceType" : "d2.8xlarge",
                "currentGeneration" : "Yes",
                "instanceFamily" : "Storage optimized",
                "vcpu" : "36",
                "physicalProcessor" : "Intel Xeon E5-2676v3 (Haswell)",
                "clockSpeed" : "2.4 GHz",
                "memory" : "244 GiB",
                "storage" : "24 x 2000 HDD",
                "networkPerformance" : "10 Gigabit",
                "processorArchitecture" : "64-bit",
                "tenancy" : "Host",
                "operatingSystem" : "Linux",
                "licenseModel" : "No License required",
                "usagetype" : "HostBoxUsage:d2.8xlarge",
                "operation" : "RunInstances",
                "enhancedNetworkingSupported" : "Yes",
                "preInstalledSw" : "NA",
                "processorFeatures" : "Intel AVX; Intel AVX2; Intel Turbo"
              }
            }
          }}'
{"_index":"productsapp","_type":"productdocs","_id":"AVu5OLfHPw6Pv_3O38-V","_version":2,"result":"updated","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":false}
```

Comment: I tried your way and it's working properly. Also the mapping's is ok.
May i ask you how did you get to the answer?

Comment: I am not sure how you were inserting? I still recommend to go and check whats the mapping for clockSpeed on the type you got error.

Comment: same as you did but just specifying the index: curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/aws/ -d '{ ~~ }'

Comment: so you created the index first? Otherwise you'd get `No handler found for uri [/aws] and method [POST]`?

Comment: no I specified the index in the request without creating it before but i didn't get the error you posted

Comment: I managed to put into Elasticsearch all my data but it creates a subfield for each document because they have different "sku". How should I proceed to "merge" this informations? I don't care about sku's specific name. Is it possibile to change it to let's say "VM" for instance? Should i change the mapping?

Comment: I did not quite understand you. Are you saying you inserted doc1 for `sku1`. Then doc2 for `sku1` but with different `attributes`? and you want those to get merged?

Comment: No, i have a big json with all the Sku subtrees under products so when i put it into ES it creates a single big document. I'd like to shirink this document into multiple docs each one corresponding to a sku so that when i search for example "ClockSpeed" it returns just the clockspeed for each document.
Sorry i'm really new to ES and I might get confused on naming

Comment: Nope, it not gonna split the huge doc automatically, how would it know they are different skus?? you have to somehow tweak it. Are you using `curl -XPOST` through CLI or using APIs like scala, python etc? If you are using `curl`, do `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@your_gian_json_file.json"` . Also the json file needs to have this format like in this doc - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: Or using APIs like scala, you have to create json object, and iterate on each sku and insert one at a time. Or still you can use bulk api, but you have let it know each line is one document.