# How to index in elasticsearch using post request in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am facing an issue:

> RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'mapper
>   [columns.analysis.abstract_stats.description.std] of different type,
>   current_type [text], merged_type [float]')

which led me to go for a solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43597278/10060068).

My current code which is generating the aforementioned error is:

```
from test_mapping import a

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'A.B.C.D', 'port': 9200}])

try:
    es.index(index='datatables', doc_type='datatable_v1', id="pallet_d3dd6729b810bebd955708e85afc1f65c3f2685c", body=a)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

The index existed before but I have deleted it and then running the above code is still generating the above error. The variable `a` is [here](https://pastebin.com/A5b0FztZ)

Comment: can you share the mapping of the doc type datatable_v1 you have used?

Comment: how can i retrieve it?

Comment: GET index/doctype/_mapping

Comment: seems like there is an issue with your mapping!

Comment: curl -XGET localhost:9200/datatable/_mapping
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"datatable","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"datatable"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"datatable","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"datatable"},"status":404}

It says no mapping exists!

Comment: curl -XGET localhost:9200/datatable_v1/_mapping
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"datatable_v1","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"datatable_v1"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"datatable_v1","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"datatable_v1"},"status":404}

Comment: also there is problem with your data too. Many documents have this columns.analysis.abstract_stats.description.std  set to 'Nan'. This is letting the ES to dynamically initialize the field as text

Comment: @AmanBansal What should I do then? Change all to text each time the data comes in?

Comment: You are using wrong curl I guess there are typos in it 
curl -XGET localhost:9200/datatables/datatable_v1/_mapping

Comment: Even with your provided request:
`curl -XGET localhost:9200/datatables/datatable_v1/_mapping`

I am getting this error:
`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"datatables","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"datatables"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"datatables","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"datatables"},"status":404}%     `

Comment: try with setting NaN to 0.0 if it can be the default value

Comment: Okay you are creating the new index while inserting the data. Correct the data. That should fix your problem

Comment: @AmanBansal I cannot. The variable a has values fetched from one ES. When I am trying to put those values in another ES, I am facing this error. So the end objective is to put the data as it is.

Comment: Okay then other ES should have the mapping. Insert the same mapping from that

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html you can refer this to create a new index along with the mapping

Comment: @AmanBansal
Can you help me with the curl command or any python script which will index with the new mapping via an  answer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to load a:

```
import simplejson
es.index(index='datatables', doc_type = 'datatable_v1', id = "pallet_d3dd6729b810bebd955708e85afc1f65c3f2685c", body = simplejson.dumps(a, ignore_nan = True))
```

This should solve your problem. Now your application will read this value as None (which is possibly the source of this corruption) and you can easily implement your functionality

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the above error is when you send data to elastic then it created dynamic field for the keys it find missing in the mapping and try to identify its type. Base on the data you are sending in `body` the value at `columns.analysis.abstract_stats.description.std` is mapped to `float` type but one of the record at key `columns.analysis.abstract_stats.description.std` has value `'NaN'` which can't be mapped to a float field and hence the error. You need to make sure that type of fields doesn't change from one record to another.